# Merging large dataframes after Generating rows with Every minute

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

First, I'd like to apologise for the uninformative title. I'll have to explain the question I have in full.

I have 4 CSV files (each 1 GB large), in a wide format, with the minute of every hour for 24 hours as columns. Each CSV file represents the quarter of the year 2020. After binding all 4 CSV's files together, they form df1 as below.

Sample df1 here:

| userID | Date | 00:00 | 00:01 | 00:02 | ... | 23:59 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 10 | 5 | 30 | ... | 80 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 | 10 | 6 | NA | ... | 9 |

As you are able to see, there can be NA values for any of the columns. Every user may not have all the dates in the year 2020. You can take these values in every time to have any arbitrary integer, below 200.

There is another DF (df2), with userID, and a start time.

Sample df2 here:

| userID | StartTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 20:01:30 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 00:01:45 |

I need to only retain the records in df2, that have non-NA values in df1 for that particular user for every minute of every hour for 7 hours starting from df2$StartTime. After which, for every hour following the startTime I need to find the median value in df1 and append it to df2.

A sample result df for the first record in df2, assuming there's no NA values for the 7*60 minutes following 2020-01-01 20:01:30:

| userID | StartTime | NumberofHoursfromStartTime | MedianValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 20:01:30 | 0 | 50 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 20:01:30 | 1 | 60 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 20:01:30 | 2 | 70 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 20:01:30 | 3 | 80 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 20:01:30 | 4 | 80 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 20:01:30 | 5 | 90 |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 20:01:30 | 6 | 100 |

This is my current method:

1. Initialize a new DF. Using a for loop, iterate through every record in df2. Generate a time vector of length 420 (7 times 60) for each record and append the vector to the new DF, along with repeated values of the StartTime and  ID. Hence, each ith time in the loop, 420 rows are being binded to the existing new DF.
2. Change df1 to long format, where there is a column with all the times and another column with the corresponding integer values.
3. Left join the DFs resulting from point 1 and point 2 = df3. Retain userIDs and StartTimes where all of the 420 minutes have populated values.
4. Find the median value for every hour from df3 after aggregation.

The issue with the current method is that there are 200,000 records in df2, and creating a df in step 1 with 200,000 times 420 rows is taking very long in using rbindlist. I suspect step 2/3 may also take very long due to the large nature of the DFs.

If anyone can think of a better way to determine which records to drop in step 3, that would be really help.

Comment: some actual sample data to wrangle with would definetely help.. Your sample data describes your question quite clear, but is provides would-be-helpers nothing to actually try their solutions on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Gather df1 "minute" columns into a single column and
2. unite new values with the date column,
3. then convert it to ymdhms format.
4. join with df2
5. DROP NA
6. Filter the values before start time
7. Create a new column "NumberofHoursfromStartTime" which calculates the the duration from start time in hours
8. group by user_id, start_time and NumberofHoursfromStartTime
9. we're done

here my example code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#example data 
df1<-tribble(
  ~userID,~Date,~"00:00",~"01:01",~"02:02",~"03:03",~"04:04",~"05:01",
  1,"2020-01-01",10,5,30,2,NA,NA,
  2,"2020-01-10",10,6,NA,4,6,3
)


# > df1
# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#       userID  Date       `00:00` `01:01` `02:02` `03:03` `04:04` `05:01`
#       <dbl>  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1     2020-01-01      10       5      30       2      NA      NA
# 2      2     2020-01-10      10       6      NA       4       6       3



#example data with 2 users
df2<-tribble(
  ~userID,~StartTime,
  1,"2020-01-01 00:01:30",
  2,"2020-01-10 02:03:45"
)

df2<-
df2%>%
  mutate(StartTime=ymd_hms(StartTime))

# > df2
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#       userID StartTime          
#       <dbl> <dttm>             
# 1      1    2020-01-01 00:01:30
# 2      2    2020-01-10 00:01:45
# > 

result<-
df1%>%
  gather(key="HourAndMinute",value="ArbInteger",-c(1,2))%>% 
  drop_na()%>%
  unite("DateWithTime",Date,  HourAndMinute,sep = " ")%>%
  mutate(DateWithTime=ymd_hm(DateWithTime))%>%
  inner_join(df2,by="userID")%>%
  filter(DateWithTime>=StartTime)%>%
  mutate(NumberofHoursfromStartTime=floor(as.duration(interval(StartTime,DateWithTime)) / dhours(1)))%>%
  group_by(userID ,StartTime,NumberofHoursfromStartTime)%>% 
  summarise(MedianValue=median(ArbInteger ))%>%
  ungroup()
  

# > result
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#     userID StartTime           NumberofHoursfromStartTime MedianValue
#     <dbl> <dttm>                                   <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1      1 2020-01-01 00:01:30                          0         5  
# 2      1 2020-01-01 00:01:30                          2        30  
# 3      1 2020-01-01 00:01:30                          3         2  
# 4      2 2020-01-10 00:01:45                          0         6  
# 5      2 2020-01-10 00:01:45                          3         4  
# 6      2 2020-01-10 00:01:45                          4         4.5
# >
```